# Laravel 5.5 and vue-typeahead - Prevent auto submit form in the onHit method

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-component

I use the [vue-typeahead](https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead) component in my Laravel project.

When I select an entry in the result list via "enter" key the enclosing form auto submits. Do you know a good way to prevent this in the onHit method?

This is my component:

```js
    import VueTypeahead from 'vue-typeahead';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;

    var elem;

    export default {
        extends: VueTypeahead,
        props: ['targetInput', 'keywordCategory', 'append'],

        data () {
            return {
                src: '/api/autocomplete',
                data: {
                    query: this.query,
                    category: this.keywordCategory,
                    append: this.append
                },
                limit: 10,
                minChars: 3,
                selectFirst: true,
                queryParamName: 'search'
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onHit (item) {
                elem = document.getElementById(this.targetInput);
                if(this.append !== undefined && elem.value !== '') {
                    elem.value += this.append + item.name;
                } else {
                    elem.value = item.name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is probably something like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

to prevent form submit on enter, handle the submit event like this

```
<form  @keypress.enter="$event.preventDefault()">
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

`@keypress.enter` is for the function being trigger when user key `enter` on input element in the form.

`$event.preventDefault()` means disable the default action, which is submitting form in this case.

No need to modify onHit in this case.

---

(Update) in order to make it work without modifying the form element, add a Vanilla JS event listener for the form in Vue's mounted function.

e.g.

```
<script>
    export default {
    ...
    mounted() {
        document.querySelector('#test-form').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (key === 13) { // 13 is enter
                // code for enter
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
}

</script>
```

example: see the ./components/Hello.vue in https://codesandbox.io/s/720zzmj7z1 .

Comment: Thanks Jacob for that quick answer. One more question:
Is it possible to attach this trigger function dynamically to the form element?

Comment: I don't really know what u mean by that

Comment: With you solution I have to modify the Laravel form view file every time I use the vue-typeahead component in my app. 

My idea/question was: Is it possible to bind the preventDefault to the form within the vue-typeahead component itself?

Comment: @hasentopf I have updated the answer. Does it work for you in Laravel?

Comment: Sorry, now the complete ENTER key doesn't work. Also the wanted vue-typeahead behavior is prevented. Your first approach was better.